# Gradle dynamic product flavor parameters

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm trying to configure the parameter resConfigs in android.defaultConfig {}. This can take multiple parameters such as resConfigs 'en', 'fa'. Now I have separated this so i have resConfig specified for each product flavor separately.

```
android {
    productFlavors.whenObjectAdded { flavor ->
        def flavorData = rootProject.ext[flavor.name]
        flavor.resConfigs flavorData.resConfig.split(",")
    }

    productFlavors {
        customization{}
    }
}
```

In a separate file i have

```
ext {

   apply from: 'locales.gradle'

   customization = [
       resConfig = rootProject.ext.locales.main
   ]
}
```

Now i want to have locales defined in a separate file as well (locales.gradle):

```
ext {
    locales = [
        main : "en,fr"
    ]
}
```

This works perfectly...however i would like to generate the locales.gradle file dynamically before the app is build, so the resConfig parameters get picked up on time. I want to run the task that generates this file from another module, the task is executed, but unfortunately not the before the product flavor gets assigned its parameters.

I have tried:

`prebuild.dependsOn ':mymodule:run'`

`commandLine 'cmd', '.\\gradlew', ':mymodule:run'`

`tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name.contains('assembleDebugFull')) {
        task.dependsOn ':mymodule:run'
    }
}`

Nothing executes the modules task before the product flavor is generated.

How can i run a task normally in gradle without that much of a hussle.

Gradle is a real pain in the ....

Comment: Let me see if I understand this right, You want the task `run` to execute before `assembleDebugFull` ?

Comment: @RaGe I would like to execute it before anything...it should be the first thing when building the app, so the productFlavors will get the correct values

Comment: You could always stick something in init.gradle, which would run before anything else. But not as a gradle task invocation, just take the code from `run` and stick it in init.gradle. Can you show your `run` task?

Comment: @RaGe Hello, sorry I was absent for a long time. In my submodule of an Android project I want to run a task. My run task looks like this (it's in build.gradle file)   `run {
    args '-m', './../app/src'
}` Which runs/compiles a java class with a path argument. Should I put the init.gradle file in my module or in the root project?